# Incorrect offset in cross reference table in pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, hex-editors

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AiOcrxB5_Eme6AgSKRznereSyns8z2Hh) pdf which was broken, i.e. its cross-reference table was damaged. I corrected this cross-reference table with the new offset values. But acrobat still shows it as broken. I used hex editor neo to calculate new offsets. are my values wrong or is there any other way to calculate offsets. any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> I corrected this cross-reference table with the new offset values.

Well, you only partially succeeded in doing so. Your cross references:

```
xref
0 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000089160 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000089295 00000 n 
0000012216 00000 n 
0000089544 00000 n 
0000012285 00000 n 
0000012433 00000 n 
0000087869 00000 n 
0000089833 00000 n 
0000088057 00000 n 
0000089662 00000 n 
00000 00000 n
```

The last entry obviously is broken, and after inspection the entries for objects 9..12 all turn out to be wrong. The correct values are:

```
xref
0 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000089160 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000089295 00000 n 
0000012216 00000 n 
0000089544 00000 n 
0000012285 00000 n 
0000012433 00000 n 
0000087869 00000 n 
0000088057 00000 n 
0000088533 00000 n 
0000089595 00000 n 
0000089662 00000 n
```

Furthermore, your start-of-cross-references value

```
startxref
91649
%%EOF
```

is wrong, in particular considering your file is less than 91000 bytes in size. The correct value is

```
startxref
89873
%%EOF
```

Furthermore, the page content stream is broken:

```
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1627>>stream
x
endstream
endobj
```

But this appears to have been done intentionally.

Comment: yeah, I guess when I deleted the stream of 4th object. I missed updating startxref value. My doubt is let's say I changed pdf's xref table with exactly yours. Now when i open pdf in acrobat and close it. It still shows the prompt that do you want to save changes to this pdf. Which I think it means that pdf is still damaged.

Comment: When I open and close it with the changes above, it doesn't prompt anymore. Thus, I assume there is some difference in what we're did. Have you paid attention to the cross reference entry size? It must be *exactly* 20 bytes...

Comment: Yepp, I checked. 10 bytes(offsets) + 1 byte(1 space) + 5 bytes( 5 digit Geneations) + 1 byte(1 space) + 1  byte(use or free) + 2 bytes(space+linefeed). I have this exact structure for all the entries.

Comment: Please share that new state of your file for analysis.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AiOcrxB5_Eme6AgSKRznereSyns8z2Hh please have a look.

Comment: They are identical. As mentioned above, though, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC does not complain here. Which version do you use? I use 2019.012.20040. Furthermore, the PDF _is_ still broken, see the object 4, "x" is _not_ a valid deflated stream, in particular not of length 1627.

Comment: I don't know what just happened. my mind is baffled. Till yesterday it was showing an error. But now it opens and closes properly. Anyway, I am happy and appreciate your efforts.